# What angled turmites make highways?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, recursion, turing-machines

I was thinking on [Langton's Ant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LangtonsAnt.html) -- what if we used different angles instead of the square, triangular, or hexagonal grids?  The concept of drop/take flags would need to change, and that can be done with a distance parameter.

So I tried that, with code at [Angled Langton's Ant](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/984368). With an angle set of  {-2 Pi/5, 2 Pi/5) and distance .15, the ant eventually makes a highway.

[image]

I tried various other angle sets, but that was the only highway I found.  What other angle sets and distance parameters form highways?

Allowing multicolored flags for full [turmite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmite) behavior, are there any angle / distance / rule sets that have interesting behavior?

Comment: Oh, hahaha.  What do you guy's see in the picture?

Comment: @Simple Art Groups of tango dancers ?